# How to remove adds from my magento website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento, code-injection

I have a magento website "http://www.nehasbags.com". when I open the website its showing one add. I don't know how it came there. I moved the live website code to my local machine. when I open the same project in my local machine the add is not displaying. Could anybody please help me to remove the add from my website/can anyone please tell me a good suggestion?

[I want to remove the add from my website. any suggestions you can share with me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL5LZ.png)

Comment: sounds like a hack to me.. ads aren't added automatically, they're manually inserted.. do you use git?

Comment: No, we are not used . that might be a hack

Comment: ah unfortunate, with git you can easily see what files werre changed and undo them

Comment: best thing I can suggest is change all passwords immediatly and go through each file relating to the page to find the ad

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ad-blocker extension on your Magento. This will help you get rid of adds and also your web pages will load faster than ever.